# Nginx JS module stream variable

Tags: nginx

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy and I need to inject the original incoming port into the actual packet (TCP/UDP) payload before sending to the upstream servers. I am trying to implement this using the NGINX's JS stream module (ngx_stream_js_module).

Here are the config files:

```
#nginx.conf

stream { 
   js_include ngin.js;       

    server {
            listen 2007;
            listen [::]:2007 udp;
            js_filter filterfn;
            proxy_pass ais_listeners;
    }

    upstream ais_listeners {
            server localhost:1111;
    }
}
```

and the JS file:

```
#ngin.js

function filterfn(s){

    var streamVars =  s.variables;
    var j = JSON.stringify(streamVars );
    s.log(j);

    s.on('upload', function(data,flags){
            s.send(streamVars.port + ',' + data, flags);
    });
}
```

streamVars.port is not defined of course.

The data are injected into the stream but the only variables I manage to use are:

```
s.remote_port
```

and

```
s.pid
```

As much as I searched I cannot find a reference of the available stream variables. Also I tried to log them using:

```
var j = JSON.stringify(streamVars )
```

which logged: null

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching in the source code I figured out the variable that hold the incoming port number is

```
s.variables.server_port
```

so the above script reads as follows:

```
#ngin.js

function filterfn(s){

    s.on('upload', function(data,flags){
            s.send(s.variables.server_port + ',' + data, flags);
            return;
    });
}
```

I hope that someone finds this useful.